# Can I use INNER JOIN on two columns of a table, refering to same Primary key of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

So I have a simple DB_Schema, **USER_INFO Table** with columns **Username and Full Name**, ***username being the primary key of this table***.
I am building a simple Chat Website. I also have a **MESSAGES Table** which has 4 columns,

- AUTOGENERATED MESSAGE ID - PRIMARY KEY
- SENDER - REFERENCES USER_INFO Table's Username
- RECEIVER - REFERENCES USER_INFO Table's Username
- MESSAGE - String of Message sent

I was trying to get details of Message, Sender(Full Name) and Receiver(Full Name) using **INNER JOIN**, MY SQL QUERY WAS :

> SELECT message, sender, user_info.name as sender, receiver, user_info.name as  receiver 
>  FROM lets_chat.privatechat 
>  INNER JOIN user_info ON privatechat.sender = user_info.username 
>  INNER JOIN user_info ON privatechat.receiver = user_info.username;

This resulted in an error : **ERROR CODE 1066: Not Unique Table/alias: 'user_info'**.
 Could someone help me correcting my error or getting me the correct SQL Statement to do this? I use **MYSQL DB**.

I am good at SPRING-HIBERNATE and I am able to do it properly in that, just needed help with SQL. **Thank You in advance**

***UPDATE ANSWER***

> SELECT PVC.message, UI1.name as sender, UI2.name as receiver 
> FROM lets_chat.privatechat AS PVC 
> INNER JOIN user_info AS UI1 ON UI1.username = PVC.sender 
> INNER JOIN user_info AS UI2 ON UI2.username = PVC.receiver;

This worked. Thank You @[plaidDK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436271/plaiddk)

Comment: You need to add a unique alias to each table reference. IOW, user_info ui1 and user_info ui2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your joins a unique alias, and refer your columns to your table ALIAS, maybe like this: **You can correct the columns to your correct table alias, hence I dont know where the columns originate from**

```
SELECT PVC.message, PVC.sender, UI1.name as sender, PVC.receiver, UI2.name as 
receiver 
FROM lets_chat.privatechat AS PVC
INNER JOIN user_info AS UI1 ON privatechat.sender = UI1.username 
INNER JOIN user_info AS UI2 ON privatechat.receiver = UI2.username;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to inform, the name of the DB Schema is lets_chat.
The two tables which are part of this schema are User_Info and PrivateChat which stores the messages.
the sender and receiver columns are referenced to same primary key of user_info table. (i.e username of User_info).
The Inner join gives me same values for both sender and receiver columns with the above query. (i.e only sender name is displayed in both sender and receiver column).

Comment: Yes! Then you just make sure your alias is the right one infront of the columns you need :)

Comment: Ok. I'm new to SQL, I have corrected my statement as follows : `SELECT privatechat.message, UI1.name as sender, UI2.name as receiver
FROM lets_chat.privatechat
INNER JOIN user_info AS UI1 ON privatechat.sender = user_info.username 
JOIN user_info AS UI2 ON privatechat.receiver = user_info.username;` But now it says Error 1054: unknown column user_info.username' in 'ON CLAUSE'.

Comment: Sorry you need to change ur alias in your ON clause as well INNER JOIN user_info AS UI1 ON privatechat.sender = UI1.username 
INNER JOIN user_info AS UI2 ON privatechat.receiver = UI2.username;